# Зацикленное выполнение кода раз в секунду

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу сделать таймкиллер,нужно постоянно выполнять определённый код раз в секунду
Использование Task.delay=1 фпс
Может знает кто как это можно реализовать?
P.S. Я новичок,не кидайте тапками

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете почитать о корутинах например здесь: https://habr.com/ru/post/216185/
. Вот пример кода, код будет выполняться раз в секунду:

```
private void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(TestCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator TestCoroutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Код
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```